# odfWeave and MS Word

Tags: r, ms-word, sweave, odt

I use odfWeave for purposes of reproducible research.  I've discovered it generally works well on MS Office 2007 using .odt files generated in Word, but `\Sexpr{}` commands almost always fail.  I suspect Word is treating the underlying XML in a strange way, but I'm curious if anyone has seen that problem and figured out how to make it work.

Thanks,

Bill

Comment: A reproducible example would help.

Comment: Fair request, Dirk.  The next time I'm at that Windows machine (likely early next week), I'll generate something.

Comment: I did a simple document that says "<<loadLibs,echo=FALSE,results=hide>>=
library(arm)
@

Lorem ipsum \Sexpr{mean(rnorm(50))} and more lorem ipsum.
"What I get out is "Lorem ipsum mean(rnorm(50))} and more lorem ipsum."

Comment: The problem is that, at least in some cases, Word puts XML markup around the \Sexpr.  For example, content.xml includes `text:style-name="T19"><text:s/></text:span><text:span
text:style-name="T20">\Sexpr{</text:span><text:span
text:style-name="T21">mean(rnorm(50)</text:span><text:span
text:style-name="T22">)</text:span><text:span
text:style-name="T23">}<text:s/></text:span><text:span` which is messed up.  I admit: I started with a longer document and kept editing it down to get to something that's not proprietary that I could share. I'll try it in LibreOffice later and update this.

Comment: That's not so easy, Dirk.  If I create a memo, I end up with small text blocks in Word that break odfWeave.  If I create a document from scratch, I don't, probably because my example documents are too simple.  I found an O'Reilly article yesterday that pointed out a similar problem with Word and odt, but I can't find it.  Their solution involved finding a way to configure Word to not issue certain page breaks on certain styles.

Comment: Now I find it: [link](http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2009/05/is-sp2-no-good-or-is-odf-no-go.html).  I don't think it directly applies, but the solution (tear apart the odt file and search for ways to get Word to stop breaking the Sexpr{} tag apart) seems promising.  It also seems like a good way to lose a lot of time.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My not use `odfCat`? E.g.:

```
> odfCat(mean(runif(100)))
<text:p text:style-name="ArialNormal">0.4411</text:p>
```

Also see [this post](http://tolstoy.newcastle.edu.au/R/e4/help/08/04/9184.html), might be related. Good luck anyway!

Comment: Thanks!  odfCat worked, although it's not quite the inline code of \Sexpr.  Now I have to read up on how to format the results of code chunks. :-)  If anyone knows how to keep Word from breaking up \Sexpr expressions, I'm still interested, but this certainly suffices.

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem. And I have found (by examining content.xml inside the .odt) that often LibreOffice will insert various inline formatting markup inside `\Sexpr{...}`, thereby preventing `odfWeave()` from working.

The solution to that is simply to mark the `\Sexpr{...}` (or the entire paragraph, or the entire document) inside LibreOffice Writer and click on "Clear direct formatting". I've never had an `\Sexpr{...}` that didn't work after doing this!